# Deleting a core data entity when updating app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

After making a rough version of my app, I am now looking to make the finalised version which is better and has many improvements. This involves changing the attributes in the entity holding the timers.

Having put the app on TestFlight already, some of the downloads will have data stored already. I am going to delete the current entity and make a new one. Will this cause any problems if data is already stored for the attributes within the entity that is going to be deleted?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make a `version` of your current coredata db.. Then in that new version, change the models and specify a mapping. If the changes are minor, a mapping won't be needed and automatic migration can be used.. However, if the changes are drastic, then your mapping will need to tell it how to convert from one version to another version.

Comment: CoreData has some limited form of data conversion when the data model is updated (like renaming attributes etc). Are you aware of this or are your modifications too complex for the automatic conversion?

Comment: I am literally deleting an entity and creating a new one in its place.

Comment: Will it cause problems? Yes. Unless you follow the migration guide. Here's a pretty good tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/174025/lightweight-migrations-in-core-data-tutorial

Comment: You can easily test this yourself, by the way. Install your app from TestFlight, add some data to that entity, then run your final app from Xcode and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know whether I made myself clear that the data I have collected so far is stuff that I don't want them to keep.